# When cookie consent for Google Analytics 4 in Google Sites will be enhanced to comply with European Union legislation?

Tags: google-analytics, cookie, privacy, google-sites, eu-cookie-law

In the Settings of a Google Site, it's possible to enable analytics and add Google Analytics 4 using a measurement ID. My concern is about the cookie consent dialog. For people accessing from the European Union, according to GDPR and ePrivacy Directive, just informing about the use of cookies and setting Google Analytics 4 cookies without prior consent doesn't comply with the law. These cookie shouldn't be set until the user opts-in. I expected this issue would be something already solved, but it isn't. I don't know if it's possible or how to request this feature, or if there is any built-in way in Google Sites to enhance the cookie consent to work similarly as the behaviour of Consent Management Platforms regarding cookies.

Google Site analytics settings:
[image: Google Site analytics settings]

Google Site cookie dialog:
[image]